# move files from subdirectories to current level and rename if exist

Tags: find, osx, mv

since I'm on a mac, the mv is a bit different which doesn't support the `--backup` attribute, the best I can come up with is

```
find . -mindepth 2 -type f -print -exec mv {} . \;
```

Comment: There is nothing stopping you (as far as I know) from installing GNU coreutils via e.g. Homebrew, on your macOS system.  That would give you access to the GNU `mv` that you seem to be familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do a bit of scripting. Something like:

```
find . -mindepth 2 -type f -print | while read x; do
    y=$(basename "$x")
    if [ -f "$y" ]; then
        mv "$y" "$y".backup
    fi
    mv "$x" "$y"
done
```

Comment: It's exactly what GNU `mv` does. I'm also assuming that other non-regular files will simply be backuped like any regular file, I see no reason why that shouldn't be done.

Comment: Good one! That should probably be `if ! [ -d "$y" ]; then` in that case.

Comment: Again you're right. I'll stop making comments, I'm not having a very bright day apparently...

Comment: No worries. It's fiddly stuff.

Answer (score 1):

To create a simple backup of the target of the `mv` command, unless it's a directory:

```
if [ -e "$target" ] && [ ! -d "$target" ]; then
    mv "$target" "$target.backup"
fi
```

This would obviously have unwanted consequences if `$target.backup` is an existing directory.  Also, we overwrite any old `$target.backup` if it exists.

It would be safer to use an enumerated backup scheme.

To create an enumerated backup of the target of the `mv` command, unless it's a directory:

```
suffix=1
if [ -e "$target" ] && [ ! -d "$target" ]; then
    while [ -e "$target.$suffix" ]; do
        suffix=$(( suffix + 1 ))
    done

    mv "$target" "$target.$suffix"
fi
```

This will rename `$target` to `$target.N` where `N` is the first positive integer that makes the filename `$target.N` unused.

Note, though, that there is a race condition here whereby *another* instance of this code (or a totally unrelated process) may create `$target.$suffix` in-between detecting that this name is unused and moving `$target` to that name.

To avoid that:

```
suffix=1
if [ -e "$target" ] && [ ! -d "$target" ]; then
    while [ -d "$target.$suffix" ] ||
          ! ln "$target" "$target.$suffix" 2>/dev/null; do
        suffix=$(( suffix + 1 ))
    done
fi
```

Now we're using `ln` to create a *new name* (hard link) for `$target`. We also skip over any integer that would generate the name of an existing directory.  This will fail until a free new name is found.

You can then do

```
mv "$source" "$target"
```

Applying this with `find` to move all regular files as you did:

```
find . -mindepth 2 -type f -print -exec sh -c '
    for source do
        target=${source##*/}
        suffix=1

        if [ -e "$target" ] && [ ! -d "$target" ]; then
            while [ -d "$target.$suffix" ] ||
                  ! ln "$target" "$target.$suffix" 2>/dev/null; do
                suffix=$(( suffix + 1 ))
            done
        fi

        mv "$source" "$target"
    done' sh {} +
```

Testing:

```
$ tree
.
|-- dir1
|   `-- file
|-- dir2
|   `-- file
`-- dir3
    `-- file

3 directories, 3 files
```

```
$ # the find command goes here
./dir1/file
./dir2/file
./dir3/file
```

```
$ tree
.
|-- dir1
|-- dir2
|-- dir3
|-- file
|-- file.1
`-- file.2

3 directories, 3 files
```

In this example, `file` would be the most recently found `file` file, `file.2` the one found before that, and `file.1` the one found first by `find`.

---

Unfortunately, the implementation of `mv -n` on macOS does not return a usable exit status. If it returned non-zero when the `mv` could not be performed, this could be used to solve this issue in an easier way with less race conditions.

Answer (score -1):

this is what I end up

```
num=1
find . -mindepth 2 -type f -print | while read x; do
    y=$(basename "$x")
    if [ -f "$y" ]; then
        mv "$y" "$y"."$num"
        num=$(( $num + 1 ))
    fi
    mv "$x" "$y"
done
```

so instead of using .backup, it could still happen if there's another same name. thanks for the inspiration!

Comment: You are potentially overwriting your backups if you run this several times. Also the numbers will be applied in a strange way, creating `1.another`, then `2.file`, if `another` and `file` are already present in the current directory.

Comment: yea, it should be "$y"."$num", right after I ran the script and I corrected it in my computer, but forgot ti edit it back here. thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: That's not quite what I meant. If a file called `another` and another file called `file` is present in the current directory, and two files with the same names are moved there, your code would move the old `another` file to `another.1` and then the `file` file to `file.2` (not to `file.1`).

Comment: I see! you're correct! but for me, my lower end solution worked for me because I want to avoid the file overwrite situation. Your solution is much better / thoughtful!